# Laravel Resource Output

Tags: laravel

Quick question,
With Laravel I want to create a json output. 
For this I use the laravel resource,

The standard resource looks like this

```
return [
    'id'                  =>      'test',
    'first'               =>      'test',
    'last'                =>      'test',
];
```

is there also a way to make the resource looks like something like this? 
what would be the best way to accomplish this.

```
return [
    'common' => [
        'status' => 'succes',
        'message' => 'succes',
    ],
    'data' => [
        'm_users' => [ 
            '0' => [ 
                'id'                  =>      '1',
                'first'               =>      'test',
                'last'                =>      'test',
            ],
            '2' => [ 
                'id'                  =>      '2',
                'first'               =>      'test',
                'last'                =>      'test',
            ],
            '3' => [ 
                'id'                  =>      '3',
                'first'               =>      'test',
                'last'                =>      'test',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Is there a way to changes the standard output that comes with the resource function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can additional data to your response like this.

```
return (new UsersResource($contacts))
            ->additional([
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message,
            ]);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks, Matt!